# How to remove the individual count under Subtotal in Excel Pivot Table with different rows count values

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I want help in removing individual count under subtotal in Excel Pivot table, where rows count contains different values.
I know this question was asked earlier but in that row count was static which contain similar values,i.e "1" but in my pivot this rows count vary. I am currently using Excel 2016 version.
Below is the link on this: 
[How to disable to remove individual count under subtotal in Excel pivot table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37982405/how-to-disable-to-remove-individual-count-under-subtotal-in-excel-pivot-table)

Below is what my pivot table data looks

[image]

Below is what I am expecting my pivot table should look

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, but I'm assuming you could use conditional formatting based on whether the cell in the "Part Number" column contains the text "Total."

Comment: ^ Tried, and it works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, could you please explain little more, how you applied this conditional formatting, since I don't know much more in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional formatting to do this, based on whether the part number column contains the text "Total."

Similarly to the linked question, you'll need `;;;` as the format.

The formula to use might be something like the following:

```
=NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Total",$A5)))
```

[image]